python script to access azure ky vault without service principle
We have stored the client id and secrets in an Azure key vault. I need to access those secrets outside azure ( from python server ) . I found a concept of using service principle to connect to azure key vault from local script, but for that
we will be having another client id and secrets ( for App registration ) . ALso I saw we can create managed identity concept to overcome the service principle problem.
Whether it's possible to access key vault using managed identiy from a local python script ? Please let me know. Thanks

Managed Identity is designed primarily for Azure resources within Azure and is not accessible directly from outside Azure environments, like a local python script.If still want to access via managed Identity create a VM and enable Identity and provide the role to that identity and login with that Identity without service principal.

For local development, you can use DefaultAzureCredential from azure.identity, which will authenticate using Azure CLI (az login) instead of a service principal. Here is my result using the default credentials.

Thank you Venkat. You mean the vault has to be created with managed identity and then the python code which you have shared we can run it locally to get the secrets ?

If you really want to use a Managed Identity, create a VM, enable Managed Identity on it, assign the Key Vault Secrets User role to the Managed Identity, and then log in to the VM using az login --identity. Follow link the  for more details about enabling identity and role assignment

Sorry..totally new to this azure..I dont want to use managed identity. Our secrets are stored in the Key vault. Somehow I need to retrieve those secrets and then I have to use it my code. I'm trying all possible option. I dont want to go with service principle as it requires app registration ( i.e. another secret ).  If i use the DefaultAzureCredential from azure.identity as per your code , will I able to retrive the secret vaules from vault ? Thanks

Yes. You can retrieve the secret values by using DefaultAzureCredential.

Can I post the same as answer with code?

Really thank you for your help. I will get the code from the screenshot..I will try this out and let you know... Thank you so much

Let us continue this discussion in chat.


python script to access azure ky vault without service principle

The System managed Identity is designed for Azure resources within azure and is not accessible directly from outside, like a local python script.If still want to access via managed Identity create a VM and enable Identity and provide the role to that identity and login with Identity without Service Principal.
For local development, you can use DefaultAzureCredential from azure.identity, which will authenticate using Azure CLI (az login) instead of a service principal.
Here is the Python code to fetch the key vault secrets using the default credentials.
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient

credential = AzureCliCredential()
client = SecretClient(vault_url="https://demo-keyvaulttest.vault.azure.net/", credential=credential)


secret = client.get_secret("Demo-Secret")
print(secret.value)


Output:


